# Why are files not found from parallel folders CMake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, include-path, cmake-language

To have my .cpp and .h files a little bit sorted up pending on their responsibilitie I decided to put them into seperate folders
I used the following structure:

**root**
|
-CMakeLists.txt [rootCmakeList]
**src**
|
-main.cpp
.......|
.......    **math**
.......|
.......-CMakeLists.txt[mathCmakeList]
.......-Algebra.h
.......-Algebra.cpp
.......**XML**[xmlCmakeList]
.......|
.......-CMakeLists.txt
.......-AwesomeXML.h
.......-AwesomeXML.cpp

The [rootCmakeList] looks:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.3)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG  "-g")

project(myProject)
#add exectuable
add_executable(myProject src/main.cpp)

target_include_directories(myProject PUBLIC "${src/XML}") 
target_include_directories(myProject PUBLIC "${src/math}") 

add_subdirectory(src/XML) 
add_subdirectory(src/math) 

target_link_libraries(myProject xml)#needed? 
target_link_libraries(myProject math)#needed?
```

The [mathCmakeList] looks:

```
include_directories(${myProject}src/math)
add_library(math Algebra.cpp)
```

The [xmlCmakeList] looks:

```
include_directories(${myProject}src/xml) 
add_library(xml AwesomeXML.cpp)
```

So far so good and no problems. But if I want to #include Algebra.h into
AweseomeXML.cpp I can not find the file.

To being honest I am not even sure if the cmake command *add_library* and *target_link_libraries* makes really sense here because I do not want to create own libraries of it  just want to tidy up a little bit my files pending on their topic.

Comment: Variable **dereference** `"${src/XML}"` has no sense. Probably, you want `"src/XML"` instead. The same is about `"${src/math}"`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev are you sure with that? This does not seem to change anything. Except the files aren't even found in main.cpp now.

Comment: I am sure that `"${src/XML}"` is wrong. I am sure that `${myProject}` is wrong too. "To being honest I am not even sure if the cmake command `add_library` and `target_link_libraries` makes really sense here because I do not want to create own libraries" - If you don't want libraries, then why do you create them? Just add all source files into `add_executable` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myProject` doesn't seem to be a variable you set. Furthermore if you properly set up the library targets, you won't need to add any of the include directories to myProject manually.

First set up the `CMakeLists.txt` file for `math`, since it doesn't depend on other projects. I recommend moving headers linking libraries use to a subdirectory. I myself usually use `include` and any path that you want the linking library to use in `#include`s starts there. Set the include dirs in a way that adds them to the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property of `math`.

```
add_library(math Algebra.cpp
    include/Algebra.h # for IDEs
)

target_include_directories(math # should be static here, since you don't want to deploy the lib by itself
    PUBLIC include # available to both math and linking libs
    PRIVATE .      # only available to math; only necessary, if there are "private" headers
)
```

Then do the same thing for `xml`, but since you're using functionality from `math`, you need to link it giving you access to its include dirs automatically, since they are available via `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`:

```
add_library(xml STATIC
    AwesomeXML.cpp
    include/AwesomeXML.h
)

target_include_directories(xml PUBLIC include)

target_link_libraries(xml PRIVATE math) # change PRIVATE to PUBLIC, if Algebra.h is included in a public header
```

Now at the toplevel we should make sure that any dependencies of a target are available before the target is defined. Also linking a lib gives you access to their respective public include directories and the public include dirs of dependencies linked publicly:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.3)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG  "-g")

project(myProject)

add_subdirectory(src/math)
add_subdirectory(src/XML) 

#add exectuable
add_executable(myProject src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(myProject PRIVATE math xml)
```